# Creating releases branch in nested style

Tags: version-control, dvcs, bazaar

I wanna have this structure:

```
project/             # The overall repository, *and* the project's mainline branch
 + joe/              # Developer Joe's primary branch of development
 |  +- feature1/     # Developer Joe's feature1 development branch
 |  |   +- broken/   # A staging branch for Joe to develop feature1
 |  +- feature2/     # Joe's feature2 development branch
 |    ...
 + barry/            # Barry's development branch
 |  ...
 + releases/
    +- 1.0/
        +- 1.1.1/
```

I'm working in a nested style repository but without the releases branches. According to what I've read, what I have to do is simply create with `bzr branch project release/X.X` the release branch? I am wrong, or there is a another and better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd project
mkdir releases
bzr branch . releases/1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be more complex!